# BigInteger throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, exception, biginteger

I'm having trouble getting a BigInteger to add another BigInteger to it.  Any suggestions
The relevant code:

Declared in class:

```
private BigInteger mTotientSum;
```

Done in constructor:

```
BigInteger mTotientSum = BigInteger.ZERO;
```

In relative method:

```
  BigInteger totientMultiplier = BigInteger.valueOf(mTotientMulitplier);
  for (long i = 1; i <= mMaxNum; i++)
  {
     BigInteger j = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
     System.out.println(j.toString());
     BigInteger num = j.multiply(totientMultiplier);
     System.out.println(num.toString());
     BigInteger totient = calculateTotient(num);
     System.out.println(totient);
     mTotientSum = mTotientSum.add(totient); //This is line 113
     System.out.println("Sum at" + i + " = " + mTotientSum.toString());
  }
```

The output I get is:

```
1
510510
17
16
16
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
          at Totient.run(Totient.java:113) (Note that line 113 is noted above.)
      at Totient.main(Totient.java:131)
```

Comment: Please add line numbers to your code so that we can tell where the NPE originated.

Comment: It was noted already...

Comment: @EngineerDollery take a look at comment after `mTotientSum = mTotientSum.add(totient);` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're shadowing the variable in the constructor. By calling

```
BigInteger mTotientSum = BigInteger.ZERO;
```

you're only initializing a local mTotientSum variable and leaving the class field null.

Don't re-declare the variable in the constructor. Instead do:

```
mTotientSum = BigInteger.ZERO;
```

See the difference?

Comment: Wow, thanks... I've been banging my head over that for 30 minutes.  I know way better than normally... Now my stupidity can be known throughout SO forever.